# "Эта статья больше не доступна" – как пишется НЕ

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, краткое-прилагательное

"Эта статья больше не доступна" – есть два аргумента на слитное и раздельное написание.

1. С "больше" пишется раздельно, потому что частица "не" относится к "больше".
   В случае "пока недоступна" – слитно.
   Проверить можно, опустив частицу "не" – если становится бессмысленным, то пишем раздельно:
   *пока недоступна – пока доступна*,
   *больше не доступна – больше доступна* (?).
2. *Недоступен* – слитное написание происходит при утверждении отрицательного признака. В этом случае мы можем заменить слово синонимом (*недоступен – скрыт*). Пишется слитно, если есть наречия меры и степени *очень, весьма, совершенно, почти*:
   *Абонент временно недоступен.

   Этот уровень игры для меня пока недоступен.

   Директор был совершенно недоступен для посетителей.

   Пароль для входа в систему был нам недоступен.

   Такой уровень ему совершенно недоступен.*

*Не доступен* – раздельное написание происходит, если имеется или подразумевается противопоставление (не доступен, а скрыт). Раздельно пишем при наличии слов *далеко, отнюдь, вовсе* или отрицательных местоимений или наречий, начинающихся с "ни" (вовсе не доступен, никому не доступен):
*Этот сайт не доступен, а заблокирован.

Этот сайт никому не доступен.

Такой вариант лечения нам вовсе не доступен.*

3. Eсли следовать проверке в п. 2, то в случае слитного написания можно заменить *недоступен* на *скрыт*, также идет аргумент в сторону раздельного написания.
   "Больше скрыт" теряет смысл.

Просьба к экспертам подсказать, какое правило превалирует.

Comment: Какие интересные вопросы! Хотелось бы услышать такой же интересный ответ. И радует, что форум стал таким оживленным.

Comment: При слитном написании другой смысл: *Эта статья больше недоступна, чем доступна.*

Comment: Annie, на сайте принято отмечать все полезные ответы и вопросы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему. Посмотрите, какой интерес вызвал Ваш вопрос!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрицая прилагательное по-разному (приставкой не или частицей не) мы меняем смысл отрицания, поэтому возможны оба варианта написания:

```
Он был не красив // и не некрасив
Он был некрасив  // именно некрасив
```

Иногда смысл не меняется, но это ничего не меняет, по-прежнему возможны два вида отрицания:

```
Он был недоступен  // одинаковый смысл
Он был не доступен // одинаковый смысл
```

Слова **далеко, отнюдь и вовсе** - что это за слова и почему они попали в какое-то правило?

Возьмем, например, такое предложение, в котором **не** заведомо является приставкой:

```
Замок был неприступен
```

Сможем мы сюда воткнуть слова *далеко* или *отнюдь*? - Нет. Значит они какие-то особенные, и их надо писать всегда с не раздельно.
А если бы часть этих слов мы бы все таки сумели воткнуть в это предложение? Тогда это были бы обычные слова никак не влияющие на слитное или раздельное написание с не.

А теперь протестируем слово больше:

```
Больше замок был неприступен. // Нет проблем, слово легко втыкается, а значит никак не влияет на раздельное либо слитное написание с не.
```

А теперь протестируем слово вовсе:

```
Замок был вовсе неприступен. // Ок. вовсе=совсем. Можем смело писать не слитно.

Вовсе замок был неприступен. // Fail. вовсе = совсем не. Подходит только раздельное написание:

Вовсе замок был не приступен. // Ок
```

Итого ответ - пишите как хотите, слова больше и вовсе (в значении совсем, но не в значении совсем не) никак не влияют на слитное или раздельное написание.

Примеры написания в книгах:

> Может быть, поэма была **вовсе недоступна** сцене?
>
> Я не большой поклонник «Алисы в Стране чудес», ненавижу игральные
> карты и зеркала, к шахматам безразличен, а прелесть математики мне
> **вовсе недоступна**
>
> А мало есть таких, которым и **вовсе недоступна** их мечта, которые тщетно
> и горько плачут от сознания недостижимости своего заветного желания,
> такого хорошего, такого благородного желания.

Еще примеры:
https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1ru&lr=lang_ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9g4bJ6aT_AhWDvosKHYWeDfw4FBCnBXoECAoQFA&biw=2195&bih=1092&dpr=1.75

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146448/discussion-on-answer-by-user190920--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Возьмите слова, которые реально без "не" не употребляются: *ненаглядный, неотразимый, необходимый, несомненный, неотъемлемый, непререкаемый, неизменный, незыблемый, непоколебимый, невероятный* (без "не" другой смысл).

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, надо обозначить **смысл** сказанного, а также работать **со словарем**.

**1. Семантика сообщения**

О чем здесь говорится? Вероятно, статья была раньше в открытом доступе, а теперь автор убрал ее. Статья (теперь, в настоящее время) стала **недоступной**.

**2. Есть ли у слова «больше» нужное нам значение?**

Смотрим в словаре: **БОЛЬШЕ.** II. нареч. 1. (с колич. сущ. и именными сочет.). 2. (в отрицат. предл.). Далее, впредь; уже. ***Б. здесь не живёт***.

Да, такое значение есть: Раньше он здесь жил, а больше (сейчас) не живет. Правда, у нас немного **другая тематика**.

**3. Смотрим слово «недоступный»** (со слитным написанием)

**НЕДОСТУПНЫЙ**, 1. Такой, к которому или по которому **нельзя пройти, проехать** и т.п. *Н-ые горные вершины. Н-ая местность.*  5. Такой, к которому **трудно подступиться**; неприступный. *Поэт недоступен для окружающих. Н-ая девушка. Я знал красавиц недоступных.*

Указанные значения **близки к нашему**: образно говоря, «к статье закрыли проход».

**Примечание.** Автор предлагает  синоним «скрыт», но сочетание «больше скрыт» некорректно. Однако сочетаемость многозначных слов —  это особая тема. Надо просто взять другой вариант: *теперь скрыт/закрыт.*

**4. Вывод** (как я думаю)

Заданное предложение для выражения нужного смысла требует стилистической правки. Корректная запись:

***Эта статья в настоящее время (сейчас, теперь) недоступна.***

Сравнить (при отсутствии правки): *Эта статья больше недоступна*.

**5. А что с вариантом**: *Эта статья больше не доступна*

Усиление отрицание (для раздельного написания) так не обозначается, а стилистика тоже сомнительная.

**Да, интересный вопрос.** Думаете по-другому? Тогда предложите свой вариант ответа, мне тоже интересно послушать (ведь вопрос дискуссионный).

Особенно меня интересует **стилистическая правка**: нужна ли она? А если нужна, то как это **объяснить**?

В комментариях под моим ответом можно уточнить его или предложить улучшение. Спасибо за то, что соблюдаете правила.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146450/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

*Больше* (более, отныне, теперь) как наречие может быть заменено другим, ему синонимичным: «Эта статья *теперь* недоступна». Здесь проблемы в ходе «проверки» не наблюдается и без *не* предложение не становится набором слов.

Но в соседстве с таким наречием, как ***больше***, оказывается неприемлемым какой-либо вариант синонима (без частицы) краткого прилагательного ***недоступна***, в этой фразе исполняющего роль сказуемого. Поэтому частицу ***не***, его часть, следует писать раздельно: «Эта статья больше не доступна».

Comment: А есть у вас правило?

Comment: У нас правила нет. Было бы правило...

Comment: Кстати, нельзя ссылаться на то, что в скобках (*являясь его частью*). О, тут ещё кое-что интересное. Частица не сама пишется, а пишется людьми, а деепричастный оборот нельзя, когда страдательный залог.

Comment: Сумбурно излагаете. Понял, что люди сами пишут частицы и что интересного ещё много кое-чего тут.

Comment: Не много, только две вещи. При изъятии вставочной конструкции не должен нарушаться смысл, а у вас нарушается. А правила Розенталя про деепричастия читали? Так вот там говорится, что деепричастие нельзя употреблять, когда страдательный залог.

Answer (score 2):

**‟НЕ” В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ: ‟ЭТА СТАТЬЯ БОЛЬШЕ НЕ ДОСТУПНА”**
‟Не” пишется раздельно, потому что тут отрицание с ‟не”, а не утверждение с ‟не”. Это можно показать на таком предложении: ‟Он больше не хороший человек”. ‟Нехороший” можно заменить на ‟плохой”, а тогда предложение будет: ‟Он больше плохой человек”, а такое предложение не имеет смысла, так как такое ‟больше” употребляется только с отрицательными словами, вроде отрицательной частицы ‟не”. Это же касается предложения: ‟Эта статья больше не доступна”.

Ещё раз, нехороший человек = плохой человек, предложение: ‟Он больше плохой человек” – бессмысленное, а поэтому предложение: ‟Он больше нехороший человек” – так же бессмысленное. Это ‟больше” без ‟не” не употребляется (или другого отрицательного слова).

**О ЗНАЧЕНИИ СОЧЕТАНИЯ ‟БОЛЬШЕ НЕ”**

Со словами в будущей форме это ‟больше” схоже со словом ‟впредь” (но не совсем, но об этом позже). Взгляните на примеры:

> Я больше не допущу эту ошибку. (Заменяется на ‟впредь”.)
> Я больше не позволю тебе так обращаться со мной. (Заменяется на ‟впредь”.)

Со словами в настоящей форме это ‟больше” схоже по смыслу с ‟сейчас”, но есть отличия, помимо того, что это ‟больше” используется только с отрицательными словами. Это ‟больше” используется тогда, когда что-то было верным ранее, а сейчас уже не является верным, тогда как ‟сейчас” может использоваться и тогда, когда это что-то не являлось верным вообще. Взгляните на примеры:

> В данный момент патчи для игры не выходят. (Не обязательно, что они вообще когда-то выходили.)
> Патчи для игры больше не выходят. (Они выходили раньше.)

Это же касается и разницы этого ‟больше” со словом ‟впредь” при отношении к слову в будущей форме.

Со словом в настоящей форме ‟больше не” = ‟перестал быть” (или ‟перестал делать”, если относится к глаголу).

> Я больше не хочу играть в эту игру = Я перестал хотеть играть в эту игру.
> Он больше не хороший человек = Он перестал быть хорошим человеком.
> Я больше не бегаю по утрам = Я перестал бегать по утрам.
> После этих поступков он больше не герой = После этих поступков он перестал быть героем.

Comment: Дырявая логика. По ней можно доказать раздельное написание в предложении "Это больше некондиционный товар". В самом деле некондиционный можно заменить на просроченный, а тогда предложение теряет смысл. Поэтому пишем раздельно "Это больше не кондиционный товар"

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое ‟некондиционный” или ‟кондиционный”, приводите примеры с понятными для большинства людей словами. По-моему, логика железная. Нехороший человек = плохой человек, предложение: ‟Он больше плохой человек” – бессмысленное, а поэтому предложение: ‟Он больше нехороший человек” – так же бессмысленное. Это ‟больше” без ‟не” не употребляется (или другого отрицательного слова).

Comment: По такой же железной логике доказываем абсурд: Нелицеприятный человек =  противный человек, предложение: ‟Он больше противный человек” – бессмысленное, а поэтому предложение: ‟Он больше нелицеприятный человек” – так же бессмысленное. Но оно звучит вполне нормально для меня. Значит логика не работает.

Comment: Если произносится слитно, то оно звучит плохо (больше нехороший человек, больше нелицеприятный человек). Оно звучит только если произносится с хотя бы крохотной паузой после ‟не” (больше не хороший человек). Точнее с паузой не меньшей, чем между ‟хороший” и ‟человек”.

Comment: Но мы же не можем писать "Он больше не лицеприятный человек" в угоду произношению? Либо мы говорим, что вся фраза вызывает какой-то смысловой диссонанс и некорректна строго говоря (так oleedd считает). Либо мы признаем слитное написание (как я).

Comment: Такое предложение никто не составит в живой речи. Носитель знает все эти моменты (неформализовано).

Comment: Ну вот мы с oleedd оба носители, и для одного носителя она звучит, а для другого нет. Можно в книги посмотреть. Там часто пишут "больше недоступна" итп

Comment: Ещё раз, носитель такое предложение не составит, так как воспринимает ‟нелицеприятный”, как ‟отвратный”. А разбирать какие-то сомнительные предложения, составленные не в живой речи, нет смысла.

Comment: Еще раз. Таких предложений миллион. И куча из них куда более живые, чем мой пример. Но я же не буду тут генерировать все слова с приставкой не на ночь глядя. "Билет больше невозвратный", "замок больше неприступный" итд

Comment: В обоих этих предложениях ‟не” пишется отдельно. Есть такая штука, как словообразование. ‟Не” считается тут неотделимой частью, но ни что мне не мешает отделить и использовать слово. Я могу взять слово ‟неприступный”, отделить ‟не” и использовать слово ‟приступный”. Я могу сказать: ‟Этот замок вполне приступный”. Если кто-то и произнесёт такие предложения, то это будет такое вот словообразование, вот и всё.

Comment: Ага, то есть вы предлагаете прямо так и писать: "Билет надорвали - больше он не возвратный." Свежо!

Comment: Да, именно так и нужно писать. В данном случае происходит словообразование. Тут проблема только в догматическом следовании правилу о неразделимых с ‟не” словах.

Comment: Недоумки не могут написать нормальный учебник по пунктуации и орфографии, – отсюда все проблемы.

Comment: "Возвратный" нормально, оно есть во всех словарях, а "приступный" просто устарело.